# How to move focus on next field when enter is pressed? I tried many approaches but nothing is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, field, enter

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>

 <head>

 <title></title>

 </head>
```

Javascript code to switch between forms by pressing enter.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).on('keypress', 'input,select', function (e) {

 if (e.which == 13) {

 e.preventDefault();

 var $next = $('[tabIndex=' + (+this.tabIndex + 1) + ']');

    console.log($next.length);

    if (!$next.length) {

        $next = $('[tabIndex=1]');
    }

    $next.focus();
}
});

</script>

<body>
```

creating forms

```
    <input type="number" name="" tabindex="1">

    <input type="number" name="" tabindex="2">

    <input type="number" name="" tabindex="3">

    <input type="number" name="" tabindex="4">

</form>

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-

q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Ive tried many approaches and the code which is working online isnt working in my computer.

Comment: Why do you need JavaScript for this? Doesn't it happen automatically?

Comment: It does by using TAB,but i need to do with Enter button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move focus on next field when enter is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209588/how-to-move-focus-on-next-field-when-enter-is-pressed)

Comment: Yes But this code isnt working in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but you have some minor mistakes that needs to be fixed.

- Your javascript code needs to be placed in the footer (before the `/body`) after the jQuery script.
- The js code needs to be placed either in the body or the head tags.
- You need to set `form` tag.

This is your code but the working version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="number" name="" tabindex="1">
        <input type="number" name="" tabindex="2">
        <input type="number" name="" tabindex="3">
        <input type="number" name="" tabindex="4">
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('keypress', 'input,select', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $next = $('[tabIndex=' + (+this.tabIndex + 1) + ']');
                console.log($next.length);
                if (!$next.length) {
                    $next = $('[tabIndex=1]');
                }
                $next.focus();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```